# Apex Controller Return events data in ISO8601 with a specified offset

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, timezone

I have a basic Apex controller that returns some `Event` data to my LWC:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
public static List<Event> getData() {
    return [SELECT Id, Subject, OwnerId, Location,
                           StartDateTime, EndDateTime, WhatId
                           FROM Event LIMIT 10]; // for brevity, there is no 'WHERE' clause
}
```

If i look at my results in JS or in Chrome dev tools, i can see that the `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime` come down ISO-8601 formatted in UTC offset, e.g. like so `2020-06-15T05:00:00.000Z`.

Is it possible to have Apex format them in a particular Timezone (e.g. `UserInfo.getTimezone()`), so that they'd come down as `2020-06-15T15:00:00.000+10:00` for `Australia/Sydney`, for example.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want date to be in that format ?

Comment: @KiranMachhewar sure is, see here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/timezone#timezone-string-like-americachicago

Answer (score 1):

You can format the date and then return a wrapper object, including the formatted datetime information.

In your example:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
public static List<FormattedEvent> getData() {
    List<Event> events = [SELECT Id, Subject, OwnerId, Location,
                          StartDateTime, EndDateTime, WhatId
                          FROM Event LIMIT 10]; // for brevity, there is no 'WHERE' clause
    System.TimeZone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();
    List<FormattedEvent> formattedEvents = new List<FormattedEvent>();
    for (Event evt : events) {
        FormattedEvent formattedEvent = new FormattedEvent(evt);
        formattedEvent.formattedStartDateTime = evt.StartDateTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ', tz.getId());
        formattedEvent.formattedEndDateTime = evt.EndDateTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ', tz.getId());
        formattedEvents.add(formattedEvent);
    }
    system.debug(formattedEvents);
    return formattedEvents;
}

public class FormattedEvent {
    public Event evt;
    public String formattedStartDateTime;
    public String formattedEndDateTime;

    public FormattedEvent(Event evt) {
        this.evt = evt;
    }
}
```

Bear in mind there's a [lightning-formatted-datetime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-date-time/documentation) base component that can help you as well.

Comment: Sadly, this worked just fine for me in anonymous window but when i slapped it into the controller and ran my code, i am getting `2020-06-22T17:00:00.000Z` converted to `2020-06-22T17:00:00.000-0700` using this method :( And even when i tried to specify the TZ using `System.TimeZone tz = System.TimeZone.getTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');` and run the code in `Australia/Sydney`, the anonymous window returns `+10:00`.

Comment: Can you try now?

Comment: I did a small tweak, and I just tried calling from a lightning component and it worked, unless I've understood your question incorrectly. In my case, what's returned is: ""StartDateTime":"2020-06-09T15:00:00.000Z" ---> "formattedStartDateTime":"2020-06-09T18:00:00.000+0300", is this what you need, right?